Strictly contracting solutions to the Eikonal equation on Riemannian manifolds
Given a Riemannian manifold $M$, we say $f: M \to \mathbb R$  is a strict contraction if $|f(x) - f(y)| < |x - y|$ for all distinct $x, y \in M$.
Question: Does there exist, on every complete Riemannian manifold, a Lipschitz function $f$ that satisfies $|\nabla f| = 1$ almost everywhere, but is a strict contraction?

Do you know an example in $\mathbb R^n$?

@GiorgioMetafune Indeed, let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be the antiderivative of $\mathbb 1_A - \mathbb 1_{A^c}$, for some set $A$ such that it and its complement are measure dense in any interval. Then $g(x) = f(|x|)$ satisfies the desired property.

To generalize your 1D example, it seems like you need to create sets whose intersection with any geodesic is measure dense in any interval (and similarly for its complement). If you can do this for $\mathbb{R}^n$, I suspect this will provide many of key ideas needed for the general case.
